# bootstrap-dropdown not displaying the dropdown where its supposed to

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get bootstrap-dropdown.js to work. But its not functioning properly. It does display a dropdown menu, but not at the right place.

I've attached a screenshot to demonstrate the issue. Also, here is the link that demonstrate the problem I am taking about [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rPRw6/)

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

This is how I am adding my nav-pills and dropdown (as mentioned in the documentation)

```
<div class="navbar masthead">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
          <li class="active">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Abcdef</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Abcdef</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Abcdef</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Abcdef</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Test</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `"dropdown"` class to each `<li>` that is supposed to have a dropdown menu. See the edited [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rPRw6/1/)

Comment: I dont know how I missed that. Thank yo uso much :)